# Simplify the expression: $(2x+1)×\left(x^2+(x+1)^2 \right)×\left( (x^4+(x+1)^4) \right)×...×\left(x^{64}+(x+1)^{64}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Simplify the expression:

$$(2x+1)×\left(x^2+(x+1)^2 \right)×\left( (x^4+(x+1)^4) \right)×...×\left(x^{64}+(x+1)^{64}\right)$$

I used the general method:

$(2x+1)(2x^2+2x+1)(2x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)×...$

But, But I'm stuck here.

Comment: This reminds me of Pascal's Triangle...

Answer (score 5):

We can rewrite the product as a telescoping one. The end result is:
$$\prod_{k=0}^6 \left((1+x)^{2^k} + x^{2^k}\right) =
\prod_{k=0}^6 \frac{(1+x)^{2^{k+1}} - x^{2^{k+1}}}{(1+x)^{2^k} - x^{2^k}}
= \frac{(1+x)^{2^7} - x^{2^7}}{(1+x)^{2^0} - x^{2^0}} = (x+1)^{128} - x^{128}$$

Answer (score 3):

Write $2x + 1 = (x+1)^2 - x^2$ and use the factorization for $a^2 - b^2$ repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

A method like this can work:

> $$\left( x+1-x\right)×\left(x+1+x \right)×\left((x+1)^2+x^2 \right)×\left( (x+1)^4+x^4\right)×...×\left((x+1)^{64}+x^{64}\right)=(x+1)^{128}-x^{128}$$